# Sylius Setup with PHP8: How can I setup a new project with the sylius-standard edition using the latest Sylius Core?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have tried to setup Sylius with the following guide: https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/getting-started-with-sylius/installation.html and with PHP 8.x. But the following command fails:

```
composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard my-shop-app
```

with several problem messages like that:

```
... 
doctrine/cache v1.6.0 requires php ~5.5|~7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement
...
```

How can I setup Sylius already now with PHP 8.x?
I have seen https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/12298 which is still open, but as it looks like it seems to be done soon. Therefore I would like to setup a sylius/sylius-standard edition with the latest changes, but don't know how to do it exactly.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Change the version of  `sylius/sylius` to `dev-master` in `composer.json` and run `composer update sylius/sylius`.

Comment: Thanks @VIctorVasiloi for your hint. I assume I need to do this after I have already executed `composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard my-shop-app` with PHP7.x? Because if I try to execute `composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard my-shop-app` with PHP8.x  I receive already the errors mentioned in the question. Or do I need to do the setup in 3 separate steps: 1. simply clone the sylius/sylius-standard repo, 2. Update sylius/sylius version in composr.json, 3. Run composer install?

Comment: You can do ​`composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard:1.9-dev my-shop-app`.

Comment: Thanks @victor-vasiloi pointing me to the right direction, I just needed to change the version according to https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/sylius-standard to "dev-master" and I could set it up with PHP8.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, in this case 1.9-dev is equal to dev-master.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, in this case 1.9-dev is equal to dev-master.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the following command:

```
composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard:dev-master my-shop-app
```